# Magento 2 custom count(*) and join example

Tags: magento2

How we can create custom query to get count(*) mean total number of matching records using join ?

Answer (score 0):

Answeris posed for my own reference and for any one who is interested to create custom join query in future. Obviously its not your 100% solution but a v good starting point.

```
$salesOrderItem = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');
        $salesOrder = $this->_resource->getTableName('sales_order');
        $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['soi' => $salesOrderItem],
            [new \Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*) as total')]
        )->join(
            ['so' => $salesOrder],
            'soi.order_id = so.entity_id',
            []
        )->where('soi.product_id = :product_id AND so.customer_id = :customer_id');
        $bind = [':product_id' => (int)$productId, ':customer_id' => (int)$customerId];
        $records = $connection->fetchOne($select, $bind);
```

Give up if it help you.